# How to test different user roles with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, cancan, dry, acceptance-testing

What would be the best way to test different authorization roles, based on abilities, with CanCan and Capybara?

I could write a `feature` for each role, but as you can see in the `Ability` class, the `:editor` and `:administrator` roles have much in common and this could lead to cluttered and repeated code. I have already tested my `Ability` class with unit tests as stated in the documentation, but testing with Capybara seems different. I could couple the editor and administrator test for the most parts with some conditionals to keep it simple and short, but coupling is bad.

Here is my `Ability` class:

```ruby
# app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(account)
    account || Account.new

    alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, to: :crud

    if account.role? :client
      can    :crud, :dashboards
      cannot :crud, :accounts
      can    :update, :accounts, id: account.id
      cannot :update, :accounts, [:role, :username], id: account.id

      cannot :crud, :sites
      can    :read, :sites, account_id: account.id
      can    :update, :sites, [:name, :description, :locales, 
                               :google_verification_code, :social_links, 
                               :display_social_icons], account_id: account.id

      can    :crud, :pages, site: { account_id: account.id }

      cannot :crud, [:themes]
    elsif account.role? :editor
      can :crud, :accounts, role: ['editor', 'client']
      can :crud, :sites
      can :crud, :pages
    elsif account.role? :administrator
      can :crud, :all
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see above, there are permissions set for [resource attributes](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/tree/2.0#resource-attributes) for the `:client` role that are being checked at the view. *(Please note that I am using the [2.0](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/tree/2.0) version of CanCan that implements such functionallity.)*

Here is the form view that performs authorization check on the attributes:

```haml
# app/views/backoffice/sites/_form.html.haml
= simple_form_for [:backoffice, @site] do |f|
  .row
    .col-lg-12
      .panel.panel-default
        .panel-heading
          %h4 Information Panel
        .panel-body
          = f.association :account             if can? :update, @site, :account_id
          = f.input :primary_domain_name       if can? :update, @site, :primary_domain_name
          = f.input :name                      if can? :update, @site, :name
          = f.input :description               if can? :update, @site, :description
          = f.input :google_verification_code  if can? :update, @site, :google_verification_code
          = f.input :activated_at, as: :string if can? :update, @site, :activated_at
          = f.input :expired_at, as: :string   if can? :update, @site, :expired_at
          = f.association :theme               if can? :update, @site, :theme_id
      = f.submit @site.new_record? ? t('actions.create') : t('actions.update'), class: 'btn'
```

Comment: This is an old question, but did you somehow get an answer or a solution to this that you wanna share with us? :-)